# Searching for a specific book set in Paris where the main character kills himself at the end?

Tags: story-identification

About 16 years ago I read a book where the main character was a male bisexual (I can't remember his name) who ultimately kills himself at the end.  The plot went something like main character lives on fringes of society, carries weapons, and lives in an apartment paid for by his absent father.  His lover is killed (I forget by who).  He takes a new female lover (who may have been called Angelique but may not be) who has had her brother digitized and stored in a pendant which she wears.  When they break up he inadvertently releases the digitized version into the internet where it gives him a sound file to play to the girlfriend which drives her insane.  He then kills himself by blowing up the (levitating) building they are in.

I remember it because it was violent, had lots of cool tech in it (ipod like devices, hoverskates etc) and the main character talked about music all the time.  It discussed things like digitizing people and street cameras to watch people earlier than other stories which I had read, and so discussed the "near future", parts of which have now arrived.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope hoverskates are near.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it! ["Bad Voltage" by Jonathan Littell.](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bad-Voltage-Jonathan-Littell/dp/0747405840/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8)

> Life is cheap in riot-torn Paris, and no one knows it better than the Livewires, a doped-out gang of bio-enhanced delinquents. When Lynx, a Livewire, becomes involved with an Uptown heiress, their relationship sparks a war between Uptowners and Downtowners that could completely destroy their city!

Comment: I added a plot summary from Goodreads. I don't suppose you could provide some details from the book that match your question?

Answer (score 3):

I've never read the book.  But after googling for a very long time I came across the story "Paris in the Twentieth Century" by Jules Verne.

Here is a [link to the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_in_the_Twentieth_Century) about the story.  It was similar enough to what you described that I think it may be what you are looking for.

Here is the book [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/034542039X) unfortunately they don't have a Kindle version though.

I hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: I no longer think this answer is correct.  But I will leave it so the asker of the question can at least take a look.

Comment: Thanks for replying - I don't think this is the book, but it does look like it's worth reading though.

Comment: Nope, Jules Verne's lost novel does not feature digitization of people. He had a neat idea of a "visual telegraph", though, but that's as far as it went.